# How do I find the name of folder with wildcard matching at least one character in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, directory, character, wildcard

I am working on an Excel spreadhseet and trying to figure out how to use wildcards. I have many subfolders in a folder called Projects. I need to be able to search and find the name of a specific folder inside using the project number. So, the folder names are of the type:

5123_Smith_Croydon

4378_Cook_Manchester

and so on.

So I have the following code, which works fine:

```
folderLoc = "C:\PROJECTS\"
projectNum = Range("A2").Value2 'this is just a 4 digit number representing the project number
folderName = Dir(folderLoc & projectNum & "*", vbDirectory)
```

However, some project folder are just called:

5234_

and then the next folder would be the actual:

5234_Harvey_Glasgow

So I am looking for a way to find the second (the longer one containing the name and the city), but my code only finds the first (5234_).

I tried the following but it just does not work and I do not understand why:

```
folderLoc = "C:\PROJECTS\"
projectNum = Range("A2").Value2 'this is just a 4 digit number representing the project number
folderName = Dir(folderLoc & projectNum & "*[A-Z]*", vbDirectory)
```

Could you please help me with a wildcard combination that effectively searches for "contains at least one character after the underscore". This one character is always a capital letter if this would make it simpler.

Thank you in advance

Comment: try `folderName = Dir(folderLoc & projectNum & "*", vbDirectory)`

Comment: File mask wildcard expressions don't support regular expressions. You can do it after the call to `Dir` in your VBA code instead.

Comment: I think the best you can do at this level would be something like:  `Dir(folderLoc & projectNum & "_?*", vbDirectory)` That should pass if there is anything after the underscore, but not if the name ends with the underscore.

Comment: Thank you, Ron, this solved it! And it makes absolute sense, should have thought about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify a class of character after the underscore, but you can specify that there IS a character after the underscore, using the `?` wildcard.

```
Dir(folderLoc & projectNum & "_?*", vbDirectory)
```

If that doesn't work, then you could read in the entire directory, and process the list using more complex methods, or Regular Expressions.